# Can't upload Xively feeds with an Arduino GSM shield

Tags: arduino, gsm, xively

I was trying to upload a Xively feed with an Arduino connected via an Arduino GSM shield.

Xively does not publish any specific example for an Arduino GSM shield. I tried to use the Arduino GSM Pachube Client library changing "pachube.com" in "xively.com", but it did not work. It seems that my GSM shield is able to connect but cannot put the data to the server.

In my example I created a device called "Arduino GSM" with just one channel called "sensor1". In the request log I cannot read any request incoming, although the serial monitor shows that a connection with the server occurs.

This is the code I tried:

```
    // Original GSM Pachube client modified for Xively
    // Changes: pachube.com -> xively.com
    // inserted APIKEY, FEEDID, USERAGENT
    // inserted GPRS_APN, login, password

    /*GSM Pachube client

     This sketch connects an analog sensor to Pachube (http://www.pachube.com)
     using a Telefonica GSM/GPRS shield.

     This example has been updated to use version 2.0 of the Pachube.com API. 
     To make it work, create a feed with a datastream, and give it the ID
     sensor1. Or change the code below to match your feed.

     Circuit:
     * Analog sensor attached to analog in 0
     * GSM shield attached to an Arduino
     * SIM card with a data plan

     created 4 March 2012
     by Tom Igoe
     and adapted for GSM shield by David Del Peral

     This code is in the public domain.

     http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesPachubeClient

     */

    // libraries
    #include <GSM.h>

    // Pachube Client data  -> changed in Xively Data
    #define APIKEY         "myapikey"  //                 replace your pachube api key here
    #define FEEDID         111111111                     // replace your feed ID
    #define USERAGENT      "Arduino GSM"              // user agent is the project name

    // PIN Number
    #define PINNUMBER ""

    // APN data
    #define GPRS_APN       "WINDBIZ WEB"  // replace your GPRS APN
    #define GPRS_LOGIN     ""     // replace with your GPRS login
    #define GPRS_PASSWORD  ""  // replace with your GPRS password

    // initialize the library instance:
    GSMClient client;
    GPRS gprs;
    GSM gsmAccess;

    // if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
    // use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
    // IPAddress server(216,52,233,121);    // numeric IP for api.pachube.com
    char server[] = "api.xively.com";      // name address for pachube API

    unsigned long lastConnectionTime = 0;         // last time you connected to the                 server, in milliseconds
    boolean lastConnected = false;                  // state of the connection last         time through the main loop
    const unsigned long postingInterval = 10*1000;  //delay between updates to Pachube.com

    void setup()
    {
      // initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
      Serial.begin(9600);
      while (!Serial) {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
      }

      // connection state
      boolean notConnected = true;

      // After starting the modem with GSM.begin()
      // attach the shield to the GPRS network with the APN, login and password
      while(notConnected)
      {
        if((gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY) &
            (gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD)==GPRS_READY))
          notConnected = false;
        else
        {
          Serial.println("Not connected");
          delay(1000);
        }
      }
    }

    void loop()
    {  
      // read the analog sensor:
      int sensorReading = analogRead(A0);   

      // if there's incoming data from the net connection.
      // send it out the serial port.  This is for debugging
      // purposes only:
      if (client.available())
      {
         char c = client.read();
         Serial.print(c);
      }

      // if there's no net connection, but there was one last time
      // through the loop, then stop the client:
      if (!client.connected() && lastConnected)
      {
        client.stop();
      }

      // if you're not connected, and ten seconds have passed since
      // your last connection, then connect again and send data:
      if(!client.connected() && ((millis() - lastConnectionTime) > postingInterval))
      {
      sendData(sensorReading);
      }

      // store the state of the connection for next time through
      // the loop:
      lastConnected = client.connected();
    }

    /*
      This method makes a HTTP connection to the server.
    */
    void sendData(int thisData)
    {
      // if there's a successful connection:
      if (client.connect(server, 80))
      {
        Serial.println("connecting...");

        // send the HTTP PUT request:
        client.print("PUT /v2/feeds/");
        client.print(FEEDID);
        client.println(".csv HTTP/1.1");
        client.print("Host: api.xively.com\n");
        client.print("X-ApiKey: ");
        client.println(APIKEY);
        client.print("User-Agent: ");
        client.println(USERAGENT);
        client.print("Content-Length: ");

        // calculate the length of the sensor reading in bytes:
        // 8 bytes for "sensor1," + number of digits of the data:
        int thisLength = 8 + getLength(thisData);
        client.println(thisLength);

        // last pieces of the HTTP PUT request:
        client.print("Content-Type: text/csv\n");
        client.println("Connection: close");
        client.println();

        // here's the actual content of the PUT request:
        client.print("sensor1,");
        client.println(thisData);
      } 
      else
      {
        // if you couldn't make a connection:
        Serial.println("connection failed");
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("disconnecting.");
        client.stop();
      }
      // note the time that the connection was made or attempted
      lastConnectionTime = millis();
    }

    /*
      This method calculates the number of digits in the
      sensor reading.  Since each digit of the ASCII decimal
      representation is a byte, the number of digits equals
      the number of bytes.
    */
    int getLength(int someValue)
    {
      // there's at least one byte:
      int digits = 1;

      // continually divide the value by ten, 
      // adding one to the digit count for each
      // time you divide, until you're at 0:
      int dividend = someValue /10;
      while (dividend > 0)
      {
        dividend = dividend /10;
        digits++;
      }

      // return the number of digits:
      return digits;
    }
```

Comment: Is it the official [Arduino/Telefonica](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoGSMShield) shield or some 3rd party shield?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this?